# It would always be/it will always be

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, modality

Let's say you are in a question and answer portion in a contest. And it goes like this:

> Question: What do you think is the disadvantages of being famous?
>
> You: I think your privacy. Paparazzi and the fans of a well-recognized person would be a hindrance to enjoyment of vacations, as they would always be the keenest critics of what you do. I think **it would always be like that way** OR I think **it will always be like that way**

I've never used the phrase **it would always be**(hypothetical situation). Is this correct? Because I often use the **it will always be like that** particularly and grammatically correct if **I think** is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to *Grammar and Vocabulary for First Certificate* by L.Prodromou, we shall use "will" for predictions, often with *I believe*, *I think*, *I hope*, *I expect* etc. So, saying "it **will** always be like that", you make a **prediction**.

But "it **would** always be like that" is grammatically correct too, just meaning something different. Remember the very common "I think it would be great!" Again, you are talking about your opinion. But now you sound far **less confident**. We could possibly add a few words and make a **conditional** sentence: "I think it would be great if you could join us" or "I think it would always be like that even if I found a new job and stopped being the center of attention".

In the answer to the interview question we are talking about, "would" would be better because the interviewee is describing a hypothetical situation: *Paparazzi and the fans of a well-recognized person **would** be a hindrance to enjoyment of vacations, as they **would** always be the keenest critics of what you do.* So, "*I think it **would** always be like that way*" is very natural and logical here.

Comment: Wew, I thought I was all wrong. Thx.